# Call method by condition

Tags: c#

I apologize in advance for my English.

I have a user search method. It's parameters - `login` and `strict`. The last one determines, which method should have been used for search - `Equals` (strict is true) or `Contains` (strict is false). How should I implement it? I could do two different methods, but I think it would be code repeating.

```
    public async Task<List<UserFindInfoDTO>> FindUserByLoginAsync(string login, bool strict)
    {            
        var users = await context.Users
            .Where(u => u.Nickname.Equals(login)) // change on "Contains" if strict is false
            .Select(u => new UserFindInfoDTO
            {
                Status  = u.Status,
                Id = u.Id,
                MiniAvatar =  u.Image,
                Nickname = u.Nickname                    
            })
            .ToListAsync();
            ...
        return users;
    }
```

Comment: If the code is unfinished, it's not ready for review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda expression you pass to `Where()` is where you define the condition, so this is where it makes the most sense to put all the logic for this.

```
.Where(u => strict ? u.Nickname.Equals(login) : u.Nickname.Contains(login))
```

Or for higher performance you can conditionally pass a different lambda expression:

```
Func<User,bool> checker = strict
  ? (Func<User,bool>)((User u) => u.Nickname.Equals(login))
  : (Func<User,bool>)((User u) => u.Nickname.Contains(login));

...

.Where(checker)
```

Comment: I thought about it but I am afraid that the program will check this condition for every string. Or it will check once and choose the necessary method for all strings?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH You can conditionally choose between lambda expressions, I added an example of it to my answer.

Comment: Yeah I added one too many, removed it now. And you're welcome :)

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Also I just realized I assigned the type `bool` to the lambda input instead of the user object!

Comment: Yeah, and I don't want to be meticulous, but check brackets again :D

Comment: lol I'm too tired for writing code... ok now everything should be in order

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH oh wait... I found another mistake! jeez I'm sorry for messing around with you like that... It should be `Func`, not `Action` since it has a return value.

Comment: it's okay, I understood the main idea, don't worry about little mistakes :)